# Is it possible to combine multiple step up inverters in parallel?

Tags: inverter

So my goal was to start the car off double layer capacitors, but the issue is, as any of the energy is used, the voltage drops according to the quantity of energy used. When only 20-30 percent of the total energy is used, the voltage already drops so low that the ecm\pcm starts turning on and off, turning off the starter relay.

I saw "DC-DC Step-up Power Inverter Module 10V-32V to 12V-35V". However it's only for 10 amps, and no one makes 100 amp dc-dc adjustable step up inverters. I was wondering if you could put 10 or more of them in parallel.

I was told there are issues balancing the load or something and that's why it can't be done? Can someone explain why this can't be done?

Comment: Avoid asking "is it possible..." because sure it is possible **however** it is very likely that some of the inverters will be damaged. Not everything that's **possible** is a good idea. Instead ask "will this work properly...".

Comment: I've seen plenty of Youtube demonstrations in which a sufficiently large bank of ultracapacitors starts a small car or motorcycle with no problem before the voltage drops too low. If your car needs a lot of cranking, it's probably time for an engine overhaul.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not a good idea to connect DCDC converters in parallel unless they're designed for that.

If you used DCDC converters in parallel anyway then there is no way that you can make sure that all parallel converters **share the load current equally**.

The converter which is set to the higest output voltage will take all the load and all the other converters will not do much or anything at all.

If:

- converter A is set to 20.0 V
- converter B is set to 20.1 V
- converter C is set to 20.2 V

And all their outputs are in parallel then converter C will "win", the combined output voltage will be 20.2 V. Converters A and B will not do anything as their feedback circuit will notice that the output voltage is too high (higher than what they are set to). Only when the voltage drops below 20.1 V or 20.0 V will they start to "work".

So when the output is loaded converter C will do its utmost to keep the voltage at 20.2 V. So if the load is drawing more current than converter C can deliver, converter C will be overloaded. What then happens depends on how the converters handle an overload.

The converter might "do its best", work at 100%, get hot, it might shut off if it has overtemperature protection. Only if the voltage drops below 20.1 V will converter B start helping. Even when it does, converter C still works at 100% while A does nothing.

Even if you say: "But then I'll just set them all to 20.0 V exactly" that will not work because there will **always** be small differences which will result in the same behavior.

Only if there's an additional circuit present which adjusts each converter such that they share the load equally, can this work properly.

Comment: There are plenty of COTS converters that are designed to be paralleled. Vicor, for one, has a broad range of products like that. Also, look at multi-phase converters, which are basically the same thing more tightly integrated.

Comment: that makes perfect sense. Hmm but won't it be self balancing in a way then? because if any of the converters are used, their voltage will drop, and others will help out. Or will the converts stay at their voltages?

Comment: *because if any of the converters are used, their voltage will drop, and others will help out.* True but you missed the main conclusion: how will a converter behave when operating at its maximum load for extended periods of time? In such a usage scenario I **know and expect** the converter to **fail** rather sooner than later.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie  Surely a good converter is designed to operate at its maximum load for extended periods of time? That's why it's the maximum. It's *above* the maximum load that you should be worried about IMO.

Comment: @immibis For a "good" design I agree with you. Problem is, how would you know if a design is "good"? Maybe a DCDC converter with **current limiting** which is set to for example 80% of the maximum current could do the job. Do note that current limiting is mostly done on the **output** current, the input current depends on the input voltage. At low input voltages this current can become quite large.